# Are Enchantment Points offered for Ancient Hunts lost forever?

Tags: minecraft-dungeons

As far as I know, in [Ancient Hunt](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Minecraft_Dungeons:Ancient_Hunt) mode you can offer and sacrifice a combination of equipment possessing certain runes to make different Ancient mobs spawn.

But it's also possible to offer Enchantment Points to start a hunt, which should increase the ratio of Ancient mobs found.

Hence my question:
Are those Enchantment Points sacrificed and therefore **lost forever** like the equipments?
Or can I get them back if I successfully complete the *Ancient Hunt*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, once an Ancient Hunt is started, all the weapons, armor, artifacts, and Enchantment Points used to open the portal will be destroyed for good. So it is good to be wise and think before you use the points.

Comment: Ok, so it's definitely something for late game. Thanks!